# Get position of different frequencies in sound signal

Tags: fft

Assumed I have a signal where different frequencies appear depending on the time position, i.e. a signal of $440\,\textrm{Hz}$ appears at $t=0$, a signal of $441\,\textrm{Hz}$ appears at $t=1$, a signal of $442\,\textrm{Hz}$ appears at $t=3$. Is it now possible to find out when the different signals appeared, and when they leave again, and relate that to the time position? The normal `fft` in one dimension just tells me that there are different frequencies, but not which.
My application is, that I have a sound file taken from an interferometer. The sound is generated by the interfering light beams. Different wavelengths generate different interference frequencies, but at different times. Thus I want to get the different frequencies in the resulting signal, and the time when they begin/end. The interference pattern generates a sine wave while interfering.

Comment: Wavlets can be used for time frequency localization. This means which frequency occurs at which time.

Comment: these are sinusoids? appearing in the context of what?

Comment: What do you mean "in the context of what"? They are overlapping interference frequencies measured by a microphone.

Comment: I think what the best description of when the different frequencies start and end depends on how they originated and what you are going to do with the timing information. Could you tell more about those?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo: I added an explanation, I hope that helps

Comment: You may have to specify what kind of sound is generated, as the term "frequencies" by itself is too ambiguous.

Comment: @hotpaw2: Can you specify "sound" for me? Do you mean sine/square/triangle, or something different?

Comment: Exactly. The term "frequency" alone can mean different things about sound, depending on the waveform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) is a practical tool for this kind of application. It plots successively the FFT magnitudes calculated on a time-sliding window. You end up with the frequency content plot against time. Here is an example of a [linear chirp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear) spectrogram (from mathworks) :

http://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/signal/LinearChirpExample_01.png

The [corresponding matlab function](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) carries the same name and is ready for use, you can specify the length of the sliding windows and how successive windows overlap.

Comment: This method does not provide me accurate enough results, I still have to sacrifice either time resolution or frequency resolution, which is not acceptable...

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the interferometer setup but have a look at:

Eric Jacobsen & Richard Lyons. **DSP Tips & Tricks: [The Sliding DFT](http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/DSPCourse/reference/Sliding%20DFT.pdf)**. *IEEE Signal Processing Magazine*, March 2003, pp 74–80.

Eric Jacobsen & Richard Lyons. **DSP Tips & Tricks: [An Update to the Sliding DFT](http://www.cmlab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/DSPCourse/reference/Sliding%20DFT%20update.pdf)**. *IEEE Signal Processing Magazine*, January 2004, pp 110–111.

You can use the sliding DFT (discrete Fourier transform) to calculate a windowed DFT starting at the time of each sample, not for all frequencies but for just the frequency you are interested about. See the subsections about [generalized cosine windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Generalized_Hamming_windows) in Wikipedia for the kind of windows that work with sliding DFT. Perhaps you can then use the magnitude and phase information from sliding DFT for your task.